# React code locking in endless loop - no while loops involved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Am a bit new to React and wrote this code below. The component below is for rendering a Time and Date Picker for a tale. The time and date pickers only render for those social media where the tale is scheduled to appear.

```
class TaleScheduler extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      returnData: {},
      totalNeeded: numberOfChannels(this.props.data)
    };
  }
  setSchedule = (date, channel) => {
    const returnData = update(this.state.returnData, {
      $merge: {channel: date}
    })
    this.setState({returnData: returnData})
    const { data, ScheduleTale } = this.props
    if (Object.values(this.state.returnData).length === this.state.totalNeeded) {
      FireAction(this.state.returnData, data.id)
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    return (
      <div style={{"display": "inline-block"}}>
        {data.showOnFacebook ? (<DateTimePicker data={data} image={facebook} setSchedule={this.setSchedule} />) : null}
        {data.showOnTwitter? (<DateTimePicker data={data} image={instagram} setSchedule={this.setSchedule} />) : null}
        {data.showOnInstagram ? (<DateTimePicker data={data} image={twitter} setSchedule={this.setSchedule} />) : null}
        {data.showOnApp ? (<DateTimePicker data={data} image={app} setSchedule={this.setSchedule} />) : null}
        <FlatButton label="Schedule" onClick={this.setSchedule} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This renders a set of time and date pickers based on where the tale is to be displayed. Below is the component that is being displayed

```
class DateTimePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
      time: null
    };
  }
  handleDateInput = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    })
  }
  handleTimeInput = (event, time) => {
    this.setState({
      time: time
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {setSchedule, channel} = this.props
    if (this.state.date && this.state.time) {
      setSchedule(concatenateDateAndTime(this.state.date, this.state.time), channel)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem
        leftAvatar={
          <img src={this.props.image} style={styles.scheduledChannelImgStyle} />
        }>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <DatePicker onChange={this.handleDateInput} />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <TimePicker onChange={this.handleTimeInput} />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

On selecting both the date and the time above. The entire page locks into an endless loop that caused the page to freeze. I am sure the functions are being calling each other in loop. But I do not know enough about React rendering to be able to figure out exactly why.

Comment: Why are you using `componentDidUpdate` in this way? Because that will get called once you do an action, it will `setState` in `TaleScheduler` which will re-render all of the date pickers, which will re-trigger `componentDidUpdate` so it will be stuck in a loop forever. (I think)

Comment: where is `concatenateDateAndTime` defined, or are you using some package for this

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am using componentDidUpdate because setState is not updating the time and date values immediately. In componentDidUpdate I am guaranteed to have the updatedValues and I can check if both are filled out before calling the parent.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri concatenateDateAndTime is a pure function I wrote and am importing. I left it out as I did not think it was relevant to the problem. Can add it if you wish to see it.

Comment: This could also be avoided by doing the concatenation at the places where you actually need it. If your `handleDateInput` and `handleTimeInput` functions called a callback from `TaleScheduler`, and it was responsible for concatenating instead, this would not be an issue.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That was how I was planning to proceed after I encountered the problem. However it reduced the reusability of the component. I would have liked a simple component that returns a date+time object to the calling parent div. Now that code will always have to be inserted into the parent.

Comment: I personally don't see an issue with that, since the parent is the one that actually cares about that value.

Comment: Fair point. I would have liked a straightforward import and use kinda component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `componentDidUpdate` check for the `previous date and time state values` before calling the function otherwise it will be called whenever the date and time are defined and the component is updating which it will do whenever you call the `setSchedule` function as it updates the state and parent which inturn leads to updated props being passed down to the child component.

Try

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {setSchedule, channel} = this.props
    if(prevState.date !== this.state.data || prevState.time !== this.state.time) {
        if (this.state.date && this.state.time) {
           setSchedule(concatenateDateAndTime(this.state.date, this.state.time), channel)
        }
    }
  }
```

To confirm that any update in the parent component, the child components `componentDidUpdate` is called, have a look at this snippet

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clicked: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child />
                <button onClick={() => this.setState((prevState) => ({clicked: !prevState.clicked}))} > Toggle</button>
             </div>
        )
    } 
}

class Child extends React.Component {
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       console.log('update in child called');
   }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello Child
             </div>
        )
    } 
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Shubham. That is what I was wondering about. Will updating state of parent cause a state update in all children as well?

In the case above the props being passed down by the parent do not change when parent updates. WIll that still fire componentDidUpdate on the child? If so then I would think it is non ideal behaviour.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot for taking the time. 

I think I am just not going to make both parent and child stateful and handle all update logic in the parent. This will definitely be stuff to think about when writing more components.

Comment: Yeah code structure is something to look at but remember to always perform check for state or prop updates in componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate functions if the action within them is triggering another update

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are calling method `setSchedule` inside `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. `setSchedule` method is calling `setState()`. This resulting in a call to `componentDidUpdate` which subsequently calls `setState` again. you are creating an infinite loop because there's no break condition. you can call setState inside `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentDidUpdate`.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {setSchedule, channel} = this.props
    if (this.state.date && this.state.time) {
      setSchedule(concatenateDateAndTime(this.state.date, this.state.time), channel)//Calling method that calls setstate.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ved. setSchedule is a props and method of the parent it updates the parent's state. Will that lead to a rerender of the child even if no part of the parent state is passed to the child? Further if child is rerendered it's state did not change will that still fire componentDidUpdate. Because technically the component did not update, its state and props are still the same as they were before.

Comment: Yes. If the parent component is updated, It will re-render its child component. But this can be overrided. `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` is here to help you.

Comment: thanks for the info. I think I will make the child stateless and let the parent handle all state storage. Far simpler. Wanted to make an easily pluggable component that just returns concatenated time and date. But I do not think all this tooling is worth it.