# How to make multiple inputs target the same source?

Tags: admin-on-rest

How can I create a custom input where several inputs affect only one source?
I have a custom time input as "hours:minutes:seconds" that should save the time as seconds.

What I have so far:

```
// calling the custom input with the expected source
<TimeInput source="time_A" />

// in the TimeInput component
<span>
  <Field component={NumberInput} name="hh" value={this.state.hh} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  <Field component={NumberInput} name="mm" value={this.state.mm} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  <Field component={NumberInput} name="ss" value={this.state.ss} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</span>
```

The handleChange method parses the entered value according to the name of the Field and should update the original source (in this case: "time_A"). That update is what I really can't figure out how to do.

I think the solution would be using the this.props.input.onChange but I must be doing something wrong because my this.props.input is undefined.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the full code of your component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the below component to capture date and time inputs from the user. You can probably use the same strategy to concatenate all your inputs.

```
class DateTimePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
      time: null
    };
  }
  handleDateInput = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    })
  }
  handleTimeInput = (event, time) => {
    this.setState({
      time: time
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {setSchedule, channel} = this.props
    //check for state update before actually calling function otherwise permanent re-renders will happen and page will lock`
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713614/react-code-locking-in-endless-loop-no-while-loops-involved/44713764?noredirect=1#comment76410708_44713764
    if (prevState.date !== this.state.date || prevState.time !== this.state.time) {
      if (this.state.date && this.state.time) {
     setSchedule(convertISTtoUTC(concatenateDateAndTime(this.state.date, this.state.time)), channel)
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    //id must be provided to date and time mui components - https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4659
    return (
      <div >
        </div>
          <DatePicker minDate={new Date()} id="datepick" autoOk={true} onChange={this.handleDateInput} />
          <TimePicker id="timepick" autoOk={true} pedantic={true} onChange={this.handleTimeInput} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Below is the function to concatenate the date and time and create 1 object from it. You will probably be passing it a DD, MM, YY object and creating the date from it.

```
export default (date, time) => {
  return new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(),
    time.getHours(),
    time.getMinutes()
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @kunalpareek! I had to put this task on hold for a while, but now that I got back to it, your answer helped a lot.